# How to format numeric input in React with react-hook-form to include decimal and thousands separators, zero-filling, and raw numeric value submission?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formatting, react-hook-form, yup

I want to create a form that allows the user to enter numbers in the format "1,500.00". The form should send this data to the server. However, the server only accepts numbers in the format "1500.00", so the number entered by the user must be transformed before being sent to the server.

Once the server has processed the data, it must send it back to the form. The numbers must be transformed back to the original format "1,500.00" so that they can be displayed to the user in the form.

Example input in the form:
1,500.00

Example output in the form:
1.500,00

Example input and output on the server:
Input: 1,500.00
Output: 1500.00

In addition, I want the user to be able to fill in zeros from right to left, for example:

0,00
0,01
0,15
1,50
15,00
150,00
1.500,00

In my case, I am using Material UI for the textfield, react-hook-form along with yup to validate the data entered in the form.

```
function NumericInput({ name, control, defaultValue }) {
  const { field } = useController({
    name,
    control,
    defaultValue,
    rules: {
      pattern: {
        value: /^-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/,
        message: "Invalid number format",
      },
    },
  });


<TextField
      {...field}
      label="Numeric Input"
      variant="outlined"
      onChange={(event) => {
        const value = event.target.value
          .replace(/[^0-9.,-]/g, '')
          .replace(',', '.');
        field.onChange(value);
      }}
      onBlur={(event) => {
        const value = event.target.value
          .replace(/[^0-9.,-]/g, '')
          .replace(',', '.');
        field.onBlur(value);
      }}
      error={Boolean(field.error)}
      helperText={field.error?.message}
    />
```